# Does System.Diagnostics.Trace do nothing is there are no listeners?

Tags: .net, trace, system.diagnostics

I'd like to be able to leave Trace in the live assembly, but only if the trace is NoOp.  This is for the same reason I don't want to spam the the Event Log.

So, if I output detailed operational information to the Trace methods, will they only actually be stored\collected if I have a trace listener attached?

i.e. They won't be written to the hard drive or stored somewhere?

Comment: [If a trace occurs in release, and no one is around to listen to it, does it actually write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN: Trace Listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When using Trace, Debug and TraceSource, you must have a mechanism for collecting and recording the messages that are sent. Trace messages are received by listeners. The purpose of a listener is to collect, store, and route tracing messages. Listeners direct the tracing output to an appropriate target, such as a log, window, or text file.

So when you have no listeners, the output will not be stored somewhere.

You can do this (which is the [recommended way to configure tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx) anyway) [in configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229453(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace>
    <listeners>
      <clear/>
    <listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Or from code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear();
```

Comment: Cheers, I wanted to be sure someone else had interpreted it that was too.

Comment: Also, by that rational, it would be safe to expose sensitive data via tracing, as this will only be available when a debug tracer is attached (assuming we trust the trace listener and the person using it).

Comment: @Banksy yes. System.Net uses tracing extensively when enabled, up till packet contents, even when using TLS.